# Cookie is saved and sent with every request but can't find in angularjs $cookies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cookies

Set-Cookie in response from server is saved in somewhere in the browser (i can't find it), it's send in cookie header in every request, but i can't fetch it using angularjs $cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Is the cookie marked as `httpOnly`?
If so then there is no way to access it via javascript.

Comment: There is no httpOnly,  here is a sample of the set-cookie `social-authentication=abc; Expires=Sat, 15-Oct-2016 17:04:04 GMT; Path=/

Comment: `social-authentication=abc; Expires=Sat, 15-Oct-2016 17:04:04 GMT; Path=/ `